# Hibernate Annotation, how to define two primary keys

Tags: hibernate, annotations

I have a class in java that has a numerical Id and  username (a nature primary key).

I want that Id and username be primary keys (not combined).

```
Create table (
    Int ID PK,
    String Username PK,
    String name,
    String password
)
```

How can I do this with hibernate annotations for java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only have one primary key (single field, composite key, etc) in hibernate.  The main reason is that most databases that I know only support either single or composite primary keys.  From your description it sounds like you are really just looking for the username to be unique.  For that, you do not need to define the field as a primary key column.  Instead, you can add a unique constraint to that field.  If using Annotations, then you would configure it similar to the following:

```
@Table(name="table",
    uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"username"})}
)
```

If generating the db tables from the hibernate configuration, this would defined a unique constraint on the username column in your table as well as the id primary key.  If you are manually creating your database scheme, then you would want to add the constraint to the database yourself.  Here is an example for Oracle:

```
CREATE TABLE table
(       id          numeric(10)   not null,
        username    varchar2(50)  not null,
        primary key (id),
        CONSTRAINT username_unique UNIQUE (username)
);
```